# Rust async-std strange syntax in order to resolve the conflict of read-write borrowing

Tags: rust, conflict, borrow

I am trying to write a tcp server with `async-std`, in order to resolve the confilice of read-write borrow check, I found a strange way:

```rust
use async_std::prelude::*;
use async_std::task;
use async_std::net::TcpListener;
use async_std::io::BufReader;
fn main() {
    task::block_on(async {
        let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:9000").await.unwrap();
        let mut incoming = listener.incoming();
        while let Some(stream) = incoming.next().await {
            let stream = stream.unwrap();
            println!("Client Addr: {:?}", stream.peer_addr().unwrap());
            task::spawn( async move {
                let (reader, mut writer) = (&stream, &stream); // Stange here <-----
                let reader = BufReader::new(reader);
                let mut lines = reader.lines();
                while let Some(line) = lines.next().await {
                    let mut line = line.unwrap();
                    line.push('x');
                    line.push('\n');
                    writer.write_all(line.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Strange:
`let (reader, mut writer) = (&stream, &stream); // Stange here <-----`
I wrote a verification program following this method:

```
fn main() {
    let mut arr = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let (r, mut w) = (&arr, &arr);
    for v in r.iter() {
        if v == &2 {
            w.push(5);
        }
    }
    dbg!(arr);
}
```

got error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*w` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
```

can anyone explain it ?

Comment: I just read your verification program. `w` has a type `&Vec`. `push()` needs `&mut Vec` (&mut self). When you call `w.push()`, rust will see `w` has a type `&Vec` which is not desired. Because of deref coersion it will check for `*w` and it is `Vec` type. It can be borrowed as a mutable ref but then it notices that it is behind a shared ref because of which it can't be mutated and hence you see that error.

Comment: let (r, mut w) = (&arr, &mut arr);  that will prompt that  already borrowed with immutable

Comment: Note that `let mut w = &arr` means that `w` has type `mut &Vec`, _not_ `&mut Vec` (which you need in order to mutate the vector).

Comment: Yes, because you can't have an immuatable and a muatble ref at the same time.

Comment: However [`TcpStream` implements `Clone`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.8.0/async_std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-Clone) so you should be able to clone the stream to create your `reader`.

Comment: The docs say to use `let (reader, writer) = &mut (&stream, &stream);`

Comment: I tried to wrap Vec with Arc, but the results is different with "stream: TcpStream" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works because TcpStream has the following impls:

```rust
impl Read for TcpStream
impl Write for TcpStream
impl<'_> Read for &'_ TcpStream
impl<'_> Write for &'_ TcpStream
```

The first two are the "normal" ones, the last two are the "special" ones that allow you to do this reader/writer trick.

For example: The `read()` trait method is defined like this:

```rust
pub fn read<'a>(&'a mut self, buf: &'a mut [u8]) -> ImplFuture<Result<usize>>
```

When you do `stream.read(buf)`, you're using the `impl Read for TcpStream` impl. Therefore, you're calling the method with `self` being of type `&mut TcpStream`.

When you do `let reader = &stream; reader.read(buf)`, you're using the `impl<'_> Read for &'_ TcpStream`. Therefore, you're calling the method with `self` being of type `&mut &TcpStream`.